# Is it possible to track an outsourced adwords campaign?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-ads

We have a site that is paying a 3rd party to run adwords campaigns on our behalf.  They do this using their own Adwords account and so we are unable to link it to our Google Analytics account.  We do have our own Adwords account for the site which is linked but the majority of campaigns are being run by this 3rd party.

At the moment, in our Adwords reports (ie the Adwords section within Google Analytics) we are seeing that for the majority of visits the campaign and keyword data is not set.  I am assuming that this is because even though the visit is being recognised as coming from an Adwords account, because it is not the Adwords account linked to our Analytics account, we don't get sent the campaign and keyword information.

Is this correct and if so is there a way that we can start tracking this information so that we can see for ourselves how the campaigns are performing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off if the company will not link the campaign to your Analytics account, or allow you to use your own AdWords account I would question why. The company should be using the MCC control panel. You provide them your AdWords ID they request access you grant access and they then manage your AdWords account from their login.

Have they shared access to their account with you? Have they entered your email to receive automatic reports from AdWords or are you trusting what they tell you?

What happens if they say you got 100 visits for one price when in actuality it's PPC cost was much less and they are pocketing the difference from your spending budget?

To track your links use the  AdWords URL buidler. http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1033867

Generate all the URL's to your site using tracking codes which will generate reports in your analytics account. If they won't do that stop using them demand credit for any unused ad spend and get another company to manager your PPC.

Comment: Thanks for that and sorry for the delayed reply.  Whilst I agree with what you are saying there are a few other complicating factors in this case.  What I take from this though is that in order to track the campaigns, we would need to do this in co-operation with the other company - otherwise, we can't.  Thanks again for taking the time to reply.